# Can non-US-citizen travelers from China transit through the US right now despite COVID/Coronavirus?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, transit, transit-visas

I know the US has a general entry ban right now. 2 of my Canadian friends need to return to Canada from China, and they're wondering if they can take a connecting flight through the US.

I believe this is not possible because (1) the US does not allow sterile transit and (2) entry is suspended for all who've been in China in the past 14 days.

Am I right? Or can they actually transit through the US.

[Source for 1: Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Avoiding_travel_through_the_United_States#:%7E:text=the%20United%20States%20does%20not%20allow%20sterile%20transit)

[Source for 2: Presidential proclamations](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/presidential-proclamation-coronavirus.html)

Comment: Your friends should ask the airline they want to take. The airlines themselves will be liable for the return trip if they can not legally pass-through the US. If the airlines say it's ok, just be sure to have a written record of the question and their answer. And you may want to call the American consulate/ambassy just to make sure as well.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. They need to enter the US to transit the US, an they cannot enter the US if they've been in Mainland China, Iran, the Schengen Area, the UK, Ireland, or Brazil in the previous 14 days, unless one of the exceptions apply to them (which is unlikely).